# Lookup items in nested arrays Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a products collection which has a nestedArray of product ids, I want to be able to lookup the product information OR lookup if the ID is associated with another product.

I've attached an example playground, hopefully it makes sense.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/zNiP59ueBjo

Any assistance would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this "foreignField": "_id.linkedProducts"